# createNavigatorFactory is not a function

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I am working on my React native app using Expo and I wanted to start using a navigation that uses tabs.

I installed it using npm and now, I got this issue that appears.
[image]

Here is my package.json :

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.5",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "next",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.0-alpha.63",
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got the same error. Got it resolved by

```
yarn add @react-navigation/native@next
```

You'll then need to wrap your app with NavigationNativeContainer as described [in the docs (at the end)](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 1):

I got this when working on mocking @react-navigation/native.  Adding createNavigatorFactory to the mocks fixed the issue.

```
jest.mock("@react-navigation/native", () => {
  return {
    useNavigation: () => ({ setOptions: jest.fn() }),
    useRoute: () => ({ params }),
    createNavigatorFactory: jest.fn(),
  };
});
```

Comment: you're missing closing bracket

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, re run -

> npm install @react-navigation/native

solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

try adding 
 `npm install @react-navigation/native` 
as mentioned in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/) navigation elements like bottomTabNavigation require further dependencies like 
1.`npm install @react-navigation/native` ,
 2.`expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`
3. `npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view` to work

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it